# NetworkManager Dispatcher Script Open Window

Tags: gtk, networkmanager

My use case is, that if I connect to my Wifi on work, I want to automatically start the chat application we use there. I broke this down to a single command for this question without any checks, just to show the problem:

`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/11-rocketchat.sh`:

```
dex /usr/share/applications/rocketchat-desktop.desktop > /tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

The script got execution permission and is also executed when reconnecting. But no window pops up and the content of `/tmp/test.log` is:

```
(rocketchat-desktop:1886): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:40:45.303: cannot open display:
```

How do I solve this problem? I'm within a `xserver` session, having the `i3wm` window manager active. But it looks like there is no display defined, since behind `display:` there is nothing. I tried to manually set `DESKTOP` to `0.0` as it is in my usual bash. Did not help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your script is not running inside your user session, so it doesn't know the DISPLAY (or XAUTHORITY if that happens to be required on your system). Starting user applications this way is also a bad idea for multiple other reasons (to start with the app will run as the wrong user): you should probably instead have script/program running in your user session that monitors NetworkManager and starts the chat app when needed -- it's not as simple as the dispatcher scripts but the D-Bus API that NetworkManager should allow you to do whatever you want.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen thanks for the constructive input. Can you point me to good example how to build such stuff with observing the network manager via DBUS etc? Who will control this observation process then?